# How do I use CSS to keep a drop-down menu visible when one of its items is clicked?

Tags: javascript, css

Subject: CSS drop down menus

I want to handle click events with CSS such that when a sub-item within a drop down menu is clicked that the drop menu stays visible.

... **AND** when I click a sub-item in a different drop down menu, I want the original drop down menu to disappear.

I can do all this with javascript, but that creates other problems not related to this post.

**HTML snippet**

```
<ul id="menubar">                          <!-- #menubar + -->

    <li class="drop">
        text1
        <ul class="aMenu">   <!-- drop-menu  -->
            <li>
                text11
            </li>
            <li class="daddy">   <!-- .daddy = parent of sub-menu -->
                text12
                <!--
                    sub-menu = .daddy .aMenu
                    sub-menu item = .daddy .aMenu li
                -->
                <ul class="aMenu">   <!-- sub-menu  -->
                    <li>text121</li>
                    <li>text122</li>
                </ul>
            </li>   <!-- .daddy -->
        </ul>
    </li>   <!-- drop menu item "text1" -->

</ul>
```

**existing CSS**:

```
/*
    Show drop menu when over main menu and
    show 1st sub-menu when over sub-menu's parent
*/

#menubar li:hover .aMenu {
    left: auto;
}

/*
    Hide sub-sub-menu when hovering over
    its grandparent (li:hover) menu.
*/

#menubar li:hover .aMenu .aMenu {
    left: -99999px;
}

/*
    Show 1st sub-menu when hovering over
    its parent (li:hover) .aMenu ...
    
    ... but, still keep hidden all its deeper
        sub-sub menus from above.
*/

#menubar .aMenu li:hover > .aMenu {
    left: auto;
}
```

**existing JS**:

I do have this function called within `<body onload="sfHover()">`

```
function sfHoverJQ() {

    $(document).ready(function () {
        
        $("li").on({    
            mouseenter: function(evt) {
                $(this).addClass("sfhover");
            },
        
            mouseleave: function(evt) {
                $(this).removeClass("sfhover");
                $(this).removeClass("sfclick");
            },
        
            click: function(evt) {
                $(this).removeClass("sfhover");
                $(this).addClass("sfclick");
            }
        });

    });

}
```

So I do have the `sfclick` + `sfhover` *classes* available, but I just don't know how to put it into the CSS code.

Comment: Please add your HTML *to provide an example the readers can fiddle around with (to see what you mean and to experiment with possible solutions)*

Comment: Where is the HTML code. Consider using the "add code snippet" function so we can simply 'Run' your code snippet and see what's going on wrong.

Comment: I would put this in jsfiddle and provide us a link to your code.  Your chance of getting a solution will be much higher.  https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Why would using more Javascript *create other problems not related to this post*?

Comment: CSS is great at styling, and dealing with transient interactions. It is not great at dealing with state. It is even less great at handling DOM events across nodes unless is direct descendants and direct, subsequent, siblings. TL DR, use javascript for thise case

Comment: 100% true = I have trouble adding just a small snippet to jsFiddle. I obviously can paste in the whole css + js code - but that is not what jsFiddle is intended for. When I try to add just a small tidbit, jsFiddle doesn’t work. Anyway, until I figure out adding just a small portion of css + js, I need to go back to the drawing board.